# How to Remove X-Powered-By header using web config

Tags: html, iis, http-headers, web-config

Hello i'm trying to remove **X-Powered-By header** by using my web.config. 
This is my web.config file so far,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
    <clear />
       <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
   </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But once I check, it still showing me the x-powered-by....

Answer (score 2):

```
<httpProtocol> 
 <customHeaders> 
  <remove name="X-Powered-By"/>
 </customHeaders> 
</httpProtocol>
```

See here for different options: https://blog.insiderattack.net/configuring-secure-iis-response-headers-in-asp-net-mvc-b38369030728

Answer (score -1):

Try putting this at the top your `index.php` file:

```
header_remove("X-Powered-By");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php